# Detect Single Segment RewriteRule apache

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I'm stuck in a very basic thing, I'm try to redirect a single segment url to a page

```
RewriteRule /([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?c=profile&val=$1 [NC,L]
```

this works fine for URLs like

```
sitename.com/myurl
```

But the problem is its also valid for URLS like

```
sitename.com/myurl/something
```

or

```
  sitename.com/myurl/something/x/y/z
```

I want it to only work for single segment after hostname, if I use it with ^ sign at the start it don't work at all

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You still have to use `^`, but must leave out the leading `/`

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?c=profile&val=$1 [NC,L]
```

For compatibility with older mod_rewrite versions you often see idioms like `^/?`. But current Apaches mod_rewrite strips the leading slash already (from the REQUEST_URI which RewriteRules operate from primarily).

Comment: thanks but it didn't effect at all, its sending accounts/no/a url to the same page